# HWIOAuthBundle 'Cannot register an account.' with social VK

Tags: symfony, vk, hwioauthbundle

I have problem with `HWIOAuthBundle` and `vk.com`, everything works, but some time ago I found face to face with error, after oAuth with `vk.com`

```
'Cannot register an account.'
```

I found this place `vendor/hwi/oauth-bundle/Controller/ConnectController.php:106`

```
        if (!($error instanceof AccountNotLinkedException) || (time() - $key > 300)) {
        // todo: fix this
        throw new \Exception('Cannot register an account.');
    }
```

But not understand why it's happens. I try to use another apps but it's not help. Maybe somebody knows why I got this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must specify version 3.0 api VK in vendor/hwi/oauth-bundle/OAuth/ResourceOwner/VkontakteResourceOwner.php

```
public function getUserInformation(array $accessToken, array $extraParameters = array())
{
    $url = $this->normalizeUrl($this->options['infos_url'], array(
        'access_token' => $accessToken['access_token'],
        'fields'       => $this->options['fields'],
        'name_case'    => $this->options['name_case'],
        'v'            => '3.0'
    ));

    $content = $this->doGetUserInformationRequest($url)->getContent();



    $response = $this->getUserResponse();
    $response->setResponse($content);
    $response->setResourceOwner($this);
    $response->setOAuthToken(new OAuthToken($accessToken));

    $content = $response->getResponse();
    $content['email'] = isset($accessToken['email']) ? $accessToken['email'] : null;
    if (isset($content['screen_name'])) {
        $content['nickname'] = $content['screen_name'];
    } else {
        $content['nickname'] = isset($content['nickname']) ? $content['nickname'] : null;
    }

    $response->setResponse($content);

    return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like problem is caused by recent update: https://vk.com/dev/version_update

You should add "v" parameter here:
https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/6401d53617816257208b8df384bdc47d2d701bf5/OAuth/ResourceOwner/VkontakteResourceOwner.php#L46